# Como utilizar as distribuições estatísticas do scipy e matplot através de array

Tags: python, scipy

Olá, preciso realizar a plotagem de gráficos de algumas distribuições estatísticas utilizando python3, para tanto verifiquei na documentação do scipy, de lá, após fazer algumas alterações para as minhas necessidades, obtive o seguinte código para realizar uma distribuição normal:

```
valor = [1,2,3,4,5,6,3]

from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Calculate a few first moments:

mean, var, skew, kurt = norm.stats(moments='mvsk')
print(norm.stats(moments='mvsk'))

# Display the probability density function (``pdf``):

x = np.linspace(norm.ppf(0.01), norm.ppf(0.99), 100)
print(norm.ppf(0.01))
ax.plot(x, norm.pdf(x),'r--', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='norm pdf')

rv = norm()
ax.plot(x, rv.pdf(x), 'k-', lw=2, label='frozen pdf')

vals = norm.ppf([0.001, 0.5, 0.999])
np.allclose([0.001, 0.5, 0.999], norm.cdf(vals))
r = valor

# And compare the histogram:

ax.hist(r, bins=len(valor), normed=True ,alpha=0.6, color='g', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.2)
ax.legend(loc='best', frameon=False)

plt.savefig("templates/docNORMAL.png")
#plt.show()
plt.gcf().clear()
```

Entretanto só consegui utilizar o exemplo com os números, ao utilizar uma lista com 100 valores aleatórios ele apresenta erros:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando ele devia se parecer com essa:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso saber como fazer uma lista funcionar com os exemplos da documentação pois assim conseguirei implementar os demais.

Comment: Aparentemente você esta perdido em python3 e talvez estatísticas? Percebi que você pegou o código exemplo de scipy.stats.norm e fez algumas alterações aleatórias. A primeira vista seu código esta misturando plot de Valor com plot da distribuição normal. Estou arrumando e posto como resposta logo logo.

Comment: Obrigado, eu estava mais perdido na parte da estatística, a segunda imagem eu tinha conseguido plotar corretamente, porém com meu método não consegui replicar nas outras distribuições.

Comment: De nada. Numpy é meio complicado mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há uma mistura em seu código de CDF com PDF com seus valores manuais e valores normais. Segue abaixo um exemplo que mostra o CDF e PDF de valores aleatórios normais e valores entrados manualmente.

```py
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.set_size_inches(16,4)

# Valores manuais
valores = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,3,8,8,8])
valores = np.sort(valores)               # coloca em ordem

cum = np.cumsum(valores)                 # CDF e PDF não funcionam para distribuições discretas
pmf = cum / np.amax(cum)                 # normaliza e cria o PMF

val, count = np.unique(valores, return_counts=True)  # Como PDF não vale contamos os valores
count = count / np.amax(count)                       # normaliza-se para mostrar em seguida


ax1.plot(val,count, 'r--',label='Frequencia')
ax1.plot(valores, pmf,'b--',label='PMF')
ax1.hist(valores, bins=len(valores), normed=True ,alpha=0.6, color='g', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.2)


# Valores normais
valores = norm.rvs(size=100) # pegamos de norm 100 valores aleatórios normais
valores = np.sort(valores)     # coloca em ordem

ax2.plot(valores, norm.pdf(valores),'r--',label='PDF')
ax2.plot(valores, norm.cdf(valores),'b--',label='CDF')
ax2.hist(valores, bins=len(valores), normed=True,alpha=0.6, color='g', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.2)



plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]